# Programmatically created view crashing

Tags: ios, ios5

Patients: Two controllers -- ViewController and (modally presented) RecorderViewController
Symptoms: After the RecorderViewController is modally presented, it does some work. After being dismissed, the program crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

In AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize controller = _controller;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.controller = [ViewController alloc];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.controller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RecorderViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize presentModalButton;

- (void)loadView 
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];

    self.presentModalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.presentModalButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 100, 50);
    [self.presentModalButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToRecorderButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.presentModalButton];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)goToRecorderButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    RecorderViewController *recorderVC = [RecorderViewController alloc];
    [self presentModalViewController:recorderVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.presentModalButton = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Crashes in main.m at return UIApplicationMain:
    #import

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS on?

Comment: Added main.m file boilerplate -- crashes on the autoreleasepool thanks~

Comment: Hmm, I always hated how when you miss those exceptions it just dumps you at the main block without any useful stack trace.  Try stepping through where you dismiss the modal controller to see which line is throwing the exception

Comment: remove viewDidLoad method and then try quickly?

Comment: A useful debugging technique is to set up a last chance exception handler.  A quick simulation of that is to wrap that line in main.m inside a @try/@catch block and print the exception's callStackSymbols.

Comment: viewDidLoad commented out, still crashes. I'll try stepping and then @try/@catch

Comment: So you can't try-catch the line in main because it's a unix signal, not an nsexception

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is problem in `goToRecorderButtonPressed` method.

Look, you are allocating memory for a `recorderVC` but don't initing it. You should initialize your object with on of available methods, for example, `init`:

```
- (IBAction)goToRecorderButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    RecorderViewController *recorderVC = [[RecorderViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:recorderVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Tried calling init on it, behavior doesn't change. I think it has to do with loadView/unloadView -- If I do no processing at all with the modal view and hit dismiss, no problem. If I do some work, then when I dismiss things get snafu